# How can I achieve a simple collision detection with Box2dWeb?

Tags: collision-detection, javascript, box2d

I'm a beginner in Box2dWeb, the version of Box2d for JavaScript.

I wrote a simple gravity system and I want to detect the collision between the box and the ground. When the falling box hits the ground, I want to execute simple function like

```
function sucs(){alert("the box on the floor!");};
```

this is my code

```
var CANVAS_WIDTH = 1024, CANVAS_HEIGHT = 700, SCALE = 30;

var b2Vec2 = Box2D.Common.Math.b2Vec2
        , b2BodyDef = Box2D.Dynamics.b2BodyDef
        , b2Body = Box2D.Dynamics.b2Body
        , b2FixtureDef = Box2D.Dynamics.b2FixtureDef
        , b2Fixture = Box2D.Dynamics.b2Fixture
        , b2World = Box2D.Dynamics.b2World
        , b2MassData = Box2D.Collision.Shapes.b2MassData
        , b2PolygonShape = Box2D.Collision.Shapes.b2PolygonShape
        , b2CircleShape = Box2D.Collision.Shapes.b2CircleShape
        , b2DebugDraw = Box2D.Dynamics.b2DebugDraw;

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var world = new b2World(new b2Vec2(0, 8), true);

var fixDef = new b2FixtureDef();
var bodyDef = new b2BodyDef();
fixDef.density = 1.0;
fixDef.friction = 0.5;
bodyDef.type = b2Body.b2_staticBody;
fixDef.shape = new b2PolygonShape;
fixDef.shape.SetAsBox(20, 2);
bodyDef.position.Set(10, 400 / 30 + 1.8);
world.CreateBody(bodyDef).CreateFixture(fixDef);


fixDef.density = 1.0;
fixDef.friction = 0.5;
fixDef.restitution = 0.3;

bodyDef.type = b2Body.b2_dynamicBody;
bodyDef.position.Set(50 / SCALE, 0 / SCALE);
//bodyDef.linearVelocity.Set((Math.random() * 12) + 2, (Math.random() * 12) + 2);
 fixDef.shape = new b2PolygonShape();
 fixDef.shape.SetAsBox(25 / SCALE, 25 / SCALE);
 world.CreateBody(bodyDef).CreateFixture(fixDef);

 var debugDraw = new b2DebugDraw();
    debugDraw.SetSprite(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d"));
    debugDraw.SetDrawScale(30.0);
    debugDraw.SetFillAlpha(0.5);
    debugDraw.SetLineThickness(1.0);
    debugDraw.SetFlags(b2DebugDraw.e_shapeBit | b2DebugDraw.e_jointBit);
    world.SetDebugDraw(debugDraw);


var image = new Image();
image.src = "image.png";

window.setInterval(gameLoop, 1000 / 60);

function gameLoop() {

    world.Step(1 / 60, 8, 3);

    world.ClearForces();
    context.clearRect(0, 0, CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);

    b = world.GetBodyList()
    var pos = b.GetPosition();
    context.save();
    context.translate(pos.x * SCALE, pos.y * SCALE);
    context.rotate(b.GetAngle());
    context.drawImage(image, -25, -25);
    context.restore();

    b = b.GetNext();
    pos = b.GetPosition();
    context.save();
    context.translate(pos.x * SCALE, pos.y * SCALE);
    //b.GetAngle()++;
    context.rotate(b.GetAngle());
    context.drawImage(image, -25, -25);
    context.restore();

    world.DrawDebugData();

};
```

Comment: Can you add details about what's happening when you run the code and what you have tried to resolve the problem(s) ? You could also limit the code you quote to the part that isn't working, it would be easier to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is very simple to do with collision listeners. eg.

```
var listener = new Box2D.Dynamics.b2ContactListener;
listener.BeginContact = function (contact) {
  alert("the box on the floor !");
}
world.SetContactListener(listener);
```

A good api reference for box2dweb is http://www.box2dflash.org/docs/2.1a/reference/
this is actually for the flash version, but it is the closest to the api of the box2dweb javascript version that I could find